# number of elements in Tuple<...>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Just wondering if there's an easy way to know how many elements are contained in a Tuple class

eg.

```
 var a = new Tuple<int,int>(1,2);
```

but how many elements are there?  Perhaps we don't care if we try to cast via the as keyword

```
 var a1 = a as Tuple<int>
 if(a1!=null)

 var a2 = a as Tuple<int,int>
 if(a2!=null)
```

Just after a little feedback.  Are many people using Tuple?

Comment: Sometimes I use Tuple, but since the parameters of the Tuple are unnamed I prefer using anonymous types when I can keep the usage withing a single method. Most of the times I use Tuple is in conjunction with [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx).

Comment: In what scenario are you getting a Tupple and don't already know its type? Are you writing `dynamic` code?

Comment: I know the types but the type does not tell me the intention. `new {StockCount = 4, BackOrders = 5,}` is much more self explaining than `Tuple.Create(4, 5)`.

Comment: @Kobi: yes it's a dynamic need.  Although, a small set of classes to cover all expected cases is probably better in this situation.  I just keep comming back to Tuple.  Not sure why.  Perhaps it bridges DB and generic concepts in one place for me.  I'm not currently a big anon type user, as I usually prefer a more concrete definition.  i.e. if you don't have an ORM for certain stituations, you need to be careful with LINQ.  I find Tupple / Pair / Triple useful.

Comment: @Albin - Obviously, I failed to communicate my question. I was wondering how sgtz got an Tuple without knowing its type (and the therefore its length). It looks like `a` is an `object`, and sgtz is trying to figure out what to do with it, which is a little weird. (sort of like asking, in your example, "how many properties does the anonymous class have?")

Comment: @Albin: are anon types generated at compile time?

Comment: @sgtz - Yes, they are! they are awesome. But, you cannot move them between methods, so they are not good for your ORM needs, assuming you have a data layer... Either way, the question "how many elements a tuple has" suggests you're using Tuples wrongs - they are not arrays or lists.

Comment: @sgtz, yes, they get compiled to real types with a generate type name behind the scenes.

Comment: @Albin: I've had trouble in the past with serialization using anon types.  So, I don't favour them in this situation.  If in a entity framework world, probably I'd favour anon types by default.  Can't detail the situation beyond that though (sorry).  Going back to anon types + a more LINQ-ified view of things is a medium term goal for me.  I agree with your comments about "intention".  In a few rare situations I've seen good business case for a Pair or Triple (not in this case though).  Let's add a little interop to the mix just for good measure ;-)

Comment: @Kobi: I'm definitely not using them as a list.  Checking how many generic params there are is used as a guard condition.  The cases I'm talking about here are signatures (similar to a method signature) that are useful for partitioning.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var a = new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2);
var aType = a.GetType();
var numberOfGenericParameters = aType.GetGenericArguments().Length;
```